# Check if string is in pandas Dataframe column, and create new Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

I am trying to check if a string is in a Pandas column. I tried doing it two ways but they both seem to check for a substring.

```
itemName = "eco drum ecommerce"
words = self.itemName.split(" ")
df.columns = ['key','word','umbrella', 'freq']
df = df.dropna()
df = df.loc[df['word'].isin(words)]
```

I also tried this way, but this also checks for substring

```
words = self.itemName.split(" ")
words = '|'.join(words)
df.columns = ['key','word','umbrella', 'freq']
df = df.dropna()
df = df.loc[df['word'].str.contains(words, case=False)]
```

The word was this: `"eco drum"`.

Then I did this:

```
words = self.itemName.split(" ")
words = '|'.join(words)
```

To end up with this:

```
eco|drum
```

This is the `"word"` column:

[image]

Thank you, is it possible this way to not match substrings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea. `.contains` has the regex pattern match option set to True by default. Therefore all you need to do is add anchors to your regex pattern e.g. `"ball"` will become `"^ball$"`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['key'])
df["key"] = ["largeball", "ball", "john", "smallball", "Ball"]
print(df.loc[df['key'].str.contains("^ball$", case=False)])
```

Referring more specifically to your question, since you want to search for multiple words, you will have to create the regex pattern to give to `contains`.

```
# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['word'])
df["word"] = ["ecommerce", "ecommerce", "ecommerce", "ecommerce", "eco", "drum"]
# Create regex pattern
word = "eco drum"
words = word.split(" ")
words = "|".join("^{}$".format(word) for word in words)
# Find matches in dataframe
print(df.loc[df['word'].str.contains(words, case=False)])
```

The code `words = "|".join("^{}$".format(word) for word in words)` is referred to as a generator expression. Given `['eco', 'drum']` it will return this pattern: `^eco$|^drum$`.

Comment: hey @the-realtom, not on my desktop right now, so i will try it when i get home. So you are saying, in this situation where the regex pattern is a variable, i will do something like this

df = df.loc[df['word'].str.contains("^words$", case=False)]

Thank you, it seems, This is the right track

Comment: hey @the-realtom
i tried doing something like this, but the new pandas dataframe is empty
df = df.loc[df['word'].str.contains('^words$', case=False)]

Comment: I updated my answer, I assume words is a string of a single word?

Comment: hey @the-realtom
word is something like this
"eco drum"

Then i did this
words = self.itemName.split(" ")
words = '|'.join(words)

to end up with this 
eco|drum

Thank you, is it possible this way?
Thank you

I will add it in my original message to make it clearer.

Comment: My answer has been updated, let me know if you have any questions.